# Can I create an "old polaroid" style with Nikon Picture Control?

Tags: nikon, post-processing, photo-editing, polaroid

I want my Nikon D810 to automatically post-process my shots so that they look like old polaroid/vintage photos.

Therefore I want to create a Nikon picture control configuration file (with the program "Picture Control Utility 2" from Nikon) that I can load into my camera.

But I can't find the correct settings and adjustments to archive that look..

*For some sample pictures look [here](http://cdni.condenast.co.uk/1080x720/k_n/karlie-kloss_glamour_10dec14_american-vogue_b_1080x720.jpg) or [there](https://maxnovo.files.wordpress.com/2012/11/md3_1350.jpg) (a bit older).*

Thanks!

On https://nikonpc.com/ you can play online with Nikon's picture control settings and directly download a corresponding file to upload into the camera.

This question is **not** a duplicate (like suggested in the comments) because I know the effect can be done relatively easy with Lightroom, but **I want a picture control configuration file** that I can load into my camera, so that the camera **automatically** processes each photo taken with the correct settings to produce a polaroid/vintage look. **Without** the need for manuell post-processing each photo using Lightroom.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I create a vintage 1990s Polaroid look from my DSLR?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/91771/how-can-i-create-a-vintage-1990s-polaroid-look-from-my-dslr)

Comment: Related: [Why do polaroid images look like they do?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/25965/15871)

Comment: This seems like one of those "what filter is this?" questions where someone asks how to achieve a particular look without really identifying the characteristics they want. You seem to know how to add a picture configuration to your camera, and also how to make one, so the only part of your question that remains is specifically what settings to use. Please read [Important information for asking "What's this effect?"
questions](http://meta.photo.stackexchange.com/questions/3881/) and
edit this post accordingly.

Comment: That's not the kind of thing PCU is capable of doing.